# Programar timeout hasta que termine ejecución

Tags: c#, timeout

necesito su apoyo con la siguiente duda/problema:

Tengo una página .aspx en el cual al momento de presionar un botón éste realiza varios procesos (ejecución de stored procedures y envío de mensajes vía MQ), en el transcurso en el que se ejecutan los distintos métodos mi página muestra una pantalla "Loading...", una vez que terminan de ejecutarse todos los procesos mi mensaje de Loading... desaparece y mi botón muestra un label que dice "Completado" (lo cual es correcto).

Sin embargo, internamente los procesos siguen ejecutándose, quise utilizar lo siguiente:

```
System.Thread.Sleep(time);
```

Veo que se pueden ejecutar todos los procesos, pero si el `time` que coloco dentro de esa función es más grande que el tiempo que tarda en realizarse todo el proceso entonces la pantalla continuara en "Loading..".

Suponiendo que tengo los siguientes métodos:

```
executionProcess(date, process);
searchProcess();
```

Me gustaría específicamente una forma de hacer un timeout, yo buscaría por mi parte el asignarle el valor en el código desde la pantalla, pero necesito saber como asignar el timeout hasta que se terminen esos 2 procesos, en caso de que terminen los procesos antes que el timeout especificado entonces el flujo continúa ignorando el tiempo de timeout.

Espero haber explicado lo que necesito. Cualquier comentario al respecto es bienvenido.

Comment: Los procesos que llamas son asíncronos, no?  ¿Podrías mostrar cómo los ejecutas?

Comment: En el código C# no encuentro nada asíncrono, solo se están llamando a los métodos, se realiza una consulta a las bases de datos para validar si se ejecutan o no los métodos.

Comment: Propongo otra logica... Al hacer click al boton muestres el loading y debes hacer que cuando la funciones del server acaben te devuelva una respuesta y cuando la tengas ocultas el loading

Comment: NO creo que el Sleep() sea la forma correcta de hacerlo, lo mejor es que el código asíncrono 'avise' al terminar (También nos interesa que siga si fue todo bien o no). Mejor publica tu código para decirte como atacar esto.